# :not(:last-of-type) not working for class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why doesn't `:not(:last-of-type)` work in the following situation? How can I fix it?

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/589/

HTML:

```
<div class="comment">This is Red</div>
<div class="hello">------------------</div>
<div class="comment">This is Red</div>
<div class="hello">------------------</div>
<div class="comment">Shouldn't be Red</div>
<div class="hello">------------------</div>
```

CSS:

```
.comment:not(:last-of-type) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: `:last-of-type` doesn't work on classes. It is meant for element *types*. Since all the elements are `div`s, it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: Is there something else that I can use for this situation?

Comment: I found a solution myself. I simply changed the divs to spans where the class was `.comment` and made `.comment` `display: block` in the CSS.

Comment: div:not(:nth-last-of-type(2)){color: red}

Answer (score 36):

As mentioned, the reason is because `:last-of-type` matches an element that is the last sibling of its element type, in this case `div`. Since the last `div` isn't the last `.comment`, it doesn't match.

Unlike for [the first element of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107), there is no way to use pure CSS to match the *last* element of a class, not even with an override. You should either use information about the existing structure to create a selector that will match the element you're looking for, such as:

```
.comment:not(:nth-last-child(2))
```

Or failing that, add an extra class name to the last `.comment` and exclude that, or otherwise alter the structure itself to accommodate your needs.

Answer (score 4):

if your structure never change , then :

```
div {
    color:red;
}
:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    color: black;
}
```

Would be the simple way to do : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/590/)** , [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/C23g6/592/)

`:not()` has still limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If your html structure doesn't change, you can use it as the .comment div is always followed by the .hello div.

```css
.comment:nth-last-of-type(n+4) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">This is Red</div>
<div class="hello">------------------</div>
<div class="comment">This is Red</div>
<div class="hello">------------------</div>
<div class="comment">Shouldn't be Red</div>
<div class="hello">------------------</div>
```

> "The :nth-last-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on
> their position among siblings of the same type (tag name), counting
> from the end."
>
> In: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type

Answer (score 0):

I passed through this question too, I only created a .last-child class, and set the last element as .last-child. So when I cant do this:

```
element:not(.las-child){
  /*your style*/
}
```